# sed to *not* edit HTML tags

Tags: html, sed

There are countless tutorials on how to use sed to edit/remove HTML tags, and they all tend to recommend something pretty close to...

```
sed 's/<[^>]\+>//g'
```

What I want is the reverse. I want to run sed on the content, and leave the tags alone. I tried reversing the open and close tags, but that didn't work.

For example, for the following input:

```
<p><img src="foo.jpg">the foo</p>
```

I would like to replace "foo" with "bar" only outside the tags, producing

```
<p><img src="foo.jpg">the bar</p>
```

The `img` tag is just an example. It shouldn't be specific to that.

Comment: Show sample input and your desired output for that sample input.

Comment: Use an XML parser to parse/edit XML/HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking has a lot of scope for going wrong (*e.g.* contents splitting over a line meaning valid matches escape or invalid matches appear valid), and I would do as @Cyrus suggests and use a for-purpose editor. That said, you can try a sed solution with capture groups:

```
sed 's/\(>[^<]*\)foo/\1bar/'
```

This matches anything everything between a `>` and the matchword `foo`, provided no tag opens before `foo`. The replacement is everything matched before foo (`\1`), then the replacement word `bar`, then everything matched after foo (`\2`). You'll need multiple runs to get all occurrences on one line.

If you're feeling really adventurous, however, this sed script handles the cases of multiple matches on a line, and matches splits over lines. It  overcomes my every attempt to fool it - *caveat emptor!*

```
#!/bin/bash
# replace.sh - wrap sed script for ease of controlling replacements

match="foo"
repl="bar"
infile="$1"

sed -E "
:line
s/(>[^<]*)$match/\1$repl/
//b line

/>[^<]*$/ {
    :linepump
    /^[^\n]*\n.*>/{P;D}
    N
    /(>[^<]*)$match/b line
    />[^<]*$/b linepump
} 
" $infile
```

To prevent partial alphanumeric matches (`foot => bart`), replace the second line of the sed script with

```
s/(>([^<]*[^[:alnum:]<]|))$word([^[:alnum:]]|$)/\1$repl\3/
```

(other options include `[:alpha:]` and `[:space:]`).

Here's a non-literal explanation:

1. Replace pattern space with next line
2. Apply substitute operation
3. If still matches, goto 2.
4. If the line doesn't contain a `>` or has a `<` after the last `>`, goto 1.
5. If there is a `\n` followed by a `>`, print and clear everything up to the first newline, then goto 4.*
6. Add next line to pattern space, preceded by a `\n`
7. If there is a match goto 2.
8. Goto 4.

**This shuffles the latest opening tag to the beginning of the pattern space: less buffer reallocation, smaller search space. This has a huge performance impact - 50x speedup on my machine.*

Comment: I'll give that a try when I have time for experimenting. Meanwhile, here's what I'm currently doing, which is probably not going to win any awards for elegance, but does the job. I replace all opening and closing tags with a newline and unique sequence of characters. Then I run sed on all lines that don't begin with those sequences, to edit the content. Then I reverse the process, putting the tags back. This works for both standalone and inline tags.

Comment: @user1889034 that's a reasonable way of doing things. The way you described it makes me think there's a problem: "sed on all lines that don't begin with those sequences" - presumably you mean contain as opposed to begin? What if you have `<img \n src="blah" \n />`? (Also, edited my script to make it run a lot faster)

Comment: So far, that hasn't been an issue. I have yet to see a linebreak inside a tag. So, yes, I do mean lines that don't begin with my sequence of characters.

Comment: Ah, I missed "with a newline and"